# Read the values from an array into the input text field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function which should read the values from an array to the text field. However, I am having a problem to read the zero position of an array into the text field.

```
$(function(){
    var values = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
        $('#room').val(values[0].text());  // not sure about this statement
});
```

This is my html code

```
<input id="room" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text() is for the text into an element

```
$(function(){
    var values = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
        $('#room').val(values[0]);
});
```

Exemple use of text()

```
<div>Hello World</div>
$("div").text() //this will return Hello World
```